# Constraint violation, List<Model<Type1>> to List<Model<Type2>>

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I'll try to explain this as well as I can.

Conversion:

```
Source type:      List<ConfigurationProcessFilterModel<SqlDbAccess>>
Destination type: List<ConfigurationProcessFilterModel<SQLiteDbAccess>>
```

Type definitions:

```
abstract class BaseEntityModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : IDbAccess
class ConfigurationProcessFilterModel<T> : BaseEntityModel<T> where T : IDbAccess
class SqlDbAccess : SQLBase, IDbAccess
class SQLiteDbAccess : SQLBase, IDbAccess
abstract class SQLBase
interface IDbAccess
```

What do I want to achieve:

Convert a list of models with type SqlDbAccess to SQLiteDbAccess and vice-versa.

ModelConverter:

```
public class ModelConverter<TS, TD>
    where TS : SQLBase, IDbAccess
    where TD : SQLBase, IDbAccess
{
    public static TDest Convert<TSource, TDest>(object source)
        where TSource : List<BaseEntityModel<TS>>, new()
        where TDest : List<BaseEntityModel<TD>>, new()
    {
        var sourceModel = (TSource)source;
        var destModel = new TDest();
        var destInnerType = typeof(TDest).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        foreach (var sourceItem in sourceModel)
        {
            var destItem = (BaseEntityModel<TD>)Activator.CreateInstance(destInnerType);
            destModel.Add(destItem);
        }

        return destModel;
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsEnumerable())
{
    var innerType =
        property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if(innerType == typeof(SqlDbAccess))
    {
        //List<BaseEntityModel<SqlDbAccess>>
        var sourceType = property.PropertyType;
        var sourceModelType = sourceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //List<BaseEntityModel<SQLiteDbAccess>>
        var destinationModelType = sourceModelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            .MakeGenericType(typeof(SQLiteDbAccess));
        var destinationType = typeof(List<>)
            .MakeGenericType(destinationModelType);

        var method = typeof(ModelConverter<SqlDbAccess, SQLiteDbAccess>)
            .GetMethod("Convert");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, destinationType);
        model = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { model });
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'GenericArguments[0], 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.Models.ConfigurationProcessFilterModel`1[Data.Database.SqlDbAccess]]', on 'TDest ConvertTSource,TDest' violates the constraint of type 'TSource'.'
>
> Inner Exception:
>   VerificationException: Method Data.ModelConverter`2[Data.Database.SqlDbAccess,Data.Database.SQLiteDbAccess].Convert: type argument 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.Models.ConfigurationProcessFilterModel`1[Data.Database.SqlDbAccess]]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TSource'.

Comment: why not `typeof(TD)` instead of `typeof(TDest).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]`?

Comment: @ASpirin that was an error on my part, it's fixed now though.

Comment: @NullBy7e your sample seems to work for me, I took your code added the missing class bodies and tried to reproduce, the only change I had to make was to cut the `GetType()` from `typeof(TDest).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with the following definition:

```
    public static TDest Convert<TSource, TDest, TS1, TS2>(object source) where TSource : List<TS1>, new() where TDest : List<TS2>, new() where TS1 : BaseEntityModel<TS> where TS2 : BaseEntityModel<TD>
```